# C# Windows Forms как сделать так что бы программа записывала нажатие кнопок

Tags: c#, winforms

Я хочу сделать так что бы в windows forms можно было играя в игры записывать нажатые кнопки,точнее сохраняя из в list(стринг),у меня есть 2 кнопка начать считывание кнопок и выключить считывания кнопок

Comment: Ваш вопрос низкого качества. Ознакомьтесь с информацией из справки [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Кейлоггер называется. Вам нужен Keyboard Hook.

Answer (score 0):

Добавляем в проект класс [KeyboardHook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281223/c-sharp-hook-global-keyboard-events-net-4-0)

```
   KeyboardHook kh = new KeyboardHook(true);
    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        KeyPressed();
    }

    private void KeyPressed()
    {
        kh.KeyDown += kh_KeyDown;
    }

    private async void Key_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isWrite.Checked == true)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\log.txt", true))
            {
                await sw.WriteLineAsync(Key.Text);
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void kh_KeyDown(Keys key, bool Shift, bool Ctrl, bool Alt)
    {
        Key.Text = Convert.ToString("The Key: " + key);
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверяем файл `log.txt`. Если `checkBox` был активен, то должны появится записи нажатых клавиш.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо,большое всё работает,но додумался уже до этого,но всё равно спасибо

Comment: бля мужик спасибо